# Calculating Max value of a measure in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I Need to calculate the Max value from a measure. Below is the scenario.

[image]

Expectation : Pareto%* column should return max value from RunningTotal* Measure which is 1982. Each row in Pareto%* should return 1982.

DAX which I tried:

DAX for Pareto%*

```
Pareto%* = 

MAXX(ALL(EventDetail[TimelinessBreak]),[RunningTotal*])
```

Can anyone please suggest what is wrong with the above DAX.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

DAX suggested by Marcus returning 3587177 which is incorrect.

```
Test34* =
CALCULATE (
[RunningTotal*] ,
ALL ( EventDetail )
)
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY3GE.png [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/veNrr.png]

Description for [RunningTotal*]

```
CALCULATE(
[ActualUpdates],
FILTER(
    CALCULATETABLE(
        SUMMARIZE(
            'EventDetail',
            'EventDetail'[TimelinessBreakSort],
            'EventDetail'[TimelinessBreak]
        ),
        ALLSELECTED('EventDetail')
    ),
    ISONORAFTER(
        'EventDetail'[TimelinessBreakSort], MAX('EventDetail'[TimelinessBreakSort]), DESC,
        'EventDetail'[TimelinessBreak], MAX('EventDetail'[TimelinessBreak]), DESC
    )
)
```

)

If I remove the timelinessbreak column from the table it is showing correct output with my DAX.

Comment: ?? You've just completely changed your definition for *RunningTotal**?

Comment: I pasted the wrong definition sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the added information, I suggest:

```
Pareto%* =
MAXX (
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        ALL ( EventDetail ) ,
        EventDetail[TimelinessBreak] ,
        EventDetail[TimelinessBreakSort]
    ) ,
    [RunningTotal*]
)
```

You can also try this (like your original measure), which is a bit more compact:

```
Pareto%* = 
MAXX (
    ALL ( 
        EventDetail[TimelinessBreak] ,
        EventDetail[TimelinessBreakSort]
    ) ,
    [RunningTotal*]
)
```

Comment: I am not getting the MAX count from my measure it is returning the Value 3587177 in all the rows.

Comment: Difficult to give a better answer without information on the data model.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion where it could go wrong?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Your initial attempt is wrong since you also need to remove the sorting column in the evaluation context.

Comment: It is returning the same value as RunningTotal*.

Comment: Strange. I have updated again with a new version.

Comment: Marcus you are a genius. This works like a charm. Thanks a lot. I was stuck with this for 2 days.

Comment: Root cause here is that Power BI requires the developer to handle unwanted effects of using a sort column. Very confusing since it takes a lot of discussion to reach a point where «is the dimension column sorted by another?» comes up at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

I might be mistaken, though due to your definition of *RunningTotal** you may have to use `SUMMARIZE` here:

```
=VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE(
        ALLSELECTED( EventDetail ),
        EventDetail[TimelinessBreak],
        "Running Total", [RunningTotal*]
    )
RETURN
    MAXX(
        T1,
        [Running Total]
    )
```

Comment: I am getting the output as 1 in all the rows.

Comment: Are there any other fields in your table apart from those in the screenshot you posted which you haven't told us about?

Comment: Thats all I have in a table.

Comment: Perhaps you should add the definition for *RunningTotal** to your post.

Comment: It is still showing 1

Comment: Added the description for running total

Comment: If I remove the TimelinessBreak column from the table it is showing correct  with my DAX

Comment: Have edited the post in light of your update.

Comment: I mistakenly pasted the wrong definition for RunningTotal*, Updated the correct one.